# Adding specified number of empty lines when tangling code blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In org-babel, when tangling code blocks, there is a header argument `padline`, which, when set to `yes`, adds an empty line to the end of the block. Can I specify the number of empty lines to be added? Some languages, like Python, have recommended number of empty lines after different objects, how do I make org-babel respect that, when tangling code blocks?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31738/org-mode-babel-ensure-more-than-one-empty-line-between-tangled-code-blocks-fo asks the same question, albeit 4yrs ago so code may have changed

Comment: You are right, it's exactly the same! I'll close this question.

Comment: Turns out I can't close it because the other question is on Stackexchange..